# Limits of reducing error by multiple measurements

Tags: repeated-measures, accuracy

By making repeated measurements improved accuracy is possible. What is the theoretical limit of this improvement?

For example, let's imagine I have a hydrophone array and am listening to a stationary, distant object making a noise. I know that my array has a bearing error of +/- 2 degrees standard deviation, normally distributed. The distant object makes sounds over time and the array automatically records the bearing to the sounds every second. So, I might end up with a list of measurements like:

247
247
248
247
249
247
247
246
.... etc.

Obviously I can fit the measurements to a normal distribution to determine the mean, which is more accurate than any one measurement. Is there any asymptotic limit to the accuracy I can achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we're thinking of the observations as being identically distributed random variables and the goal is estimation of the distribution mean with an arithmetic average, then this depends on whether or not measurements are uncorrelated.  In general
\begin{align}
\text{Var} \left ( \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i}{n} \right ) &= \frac{1}{n^2} \left ( \sum_{i=1}^{n} \text{Var}(X_i) + \underset{i \neq j}{\sum \sum} \text{Cov}(X_i, X_j) \right ) \\
&= \frac{1}{n^2} \left ( n \sigma^2 + 2 \binom{n}{2} \rho \sigma^2 \right ) \\
&= \frac{\sigma^2}{n} + \frac{n - 1}{n} \rho \sigma^2 \\
&\to \rho \sigma^2
\end{align}
as $n \to \infty$.  If the correlation is positive, then there's some uncertainty in our estimate that can't be erased.

Comment: Also note that if "accuracy" means how close the observed bearing is to the true bearing, then if there is an unknown systematic error/bias (normal distribution of error terms has non-zero mean) multiple measurements won't really help.